# New Code of Conduct for international sites. No link?

Tags: bug, design, localization, code-of-conduct

International sites, like SO en español or SO em português (Can't really access to Ja or Ru), doesn´t have a banner at the top pointing to the new Code of Conduct.

We are rushing to get a version 1 in SO en español. Will there be a link like in the other sites that point to the new Code? or this will not change, even when we finish translating it?

On SO:

[image]

On SO en español:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you manually navigate to `/conduct` on the localized sites?

Comment: Until we push the translation (we already have it on it's way, next build will be just perfect), we saw the english version. But that's not the point, I'm asking about the banner that has pop up in every site, except the localized ones...

Comment: I assume this is [tag:bug] (not [tag:feature-request]) and I it's relevant also for russian version too.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Maybe we will have more luck with the bug tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We'll be putting the banner up after the page is translated.  I didn't want to put the banner up before the page (or the banner) could be translated.  The banner is incredibly effective at driving traffic to a page but you only really have one shot at it, so I wanted to hold off until the page was translated and could be meaningful to the whole community.

Similarly, we didn't send the announcement email to users who just belong to a single international community. (You would have/will get one in English because you're also a member of MSE.)  We can send out an announcement to SOes when both the CoC and the email are translated.  The Transifex strings for the email have they keys `e524f8fb1a67417884f3c83dbba87faa`, `436b9bc55192b5236789b50d449308ec`, `8930f9cc033427c1dbc39fde2afe5cf4`, `3161846e9a64805b012daecaebecf455`, `ee2870500ec29bfb3c749a9db42e19da`, `9a68ee29301ef6050a4416064cf49e46`, `967e773278828caebcea3adad7b489a8`, `22016b82852b00a359ec4310832d2481`, `9a33c191265bdd4582f9f7d82db17c52`, `c4c0bcc2f298a9698612e62ac7ab53f9`, and `adb651e3e57c620b040e9c9f7acaf42e`.

Comment: Great!!!! the page is already translated.. we will start translating the mail ASAP and get back to you when we get that submited.

Comment: just remember to add to transifex the string in the banner, so we can translate it.

Comment: The banner is unfortunately not part of the translation system so it doesn't make it into Transifex.  I'm coordinating with the international CM team for when to turn it on, and I'll probably get the translation there.

Comment: Great.. no problem... thanks!

Comment: current meta post about the mail translation on SO esp is: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3616/324

Comment: @BrianNickel Now Code of Conduct is tranlated for SOes and SOru. Should we expect banner for them in the nearest future?

Answer (score 1):

You can found the link in the [help center](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help):

> [image: CoC]

Comment: Thanks for the link! We have to localized that lin too... but the question  is about the banner at the top on the site.

Comment: @gbianchi link translated :)

Comment: @gbianchi I thought any link that could be accessed via main page would be suitable. Maybe I misread something in your post.

Comment: no problem.. thanks for the answer anyway!